# Pie chart controller by slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a pie chart created using highchart and js and am able to control the slices using a slider individually, but the problem I am having is that I want the max value of the pie to be 100% and the other sliders contribute to that.

Find the pie chart created here

jsfiddle.net/vksvicky/3mv5gcto/2/

You can see by default the values total up to 100, now when I use the slider the values change accordingly and the pie chart changes, but I want to update the sliders as well accordingly, how can I achieve it.

Comment: Are you getting a valid result on the other sliders when you change just one? It seems like only the adjacent pie piece is changing size.

Comment: I know nothing about Highcharts but it looks like you'll need to find the callback for when the slices change size and have them directly affect the `value` method for that slider. http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is general idea how this can be done: http://jsfiddle.net/3mv5gcto/4/

In chart.events you can, after redraw, set values for all of sliders (note: I've set reference for sliders to the points, just to have them easy to use):

```
        events: {
            redraw: function () {
                //update sliders   
                $.each(chart.series[0].points, function (i, point) {
                    point.slider.slider('value', point.percentage);
                });
            }
        }
```

Now, the only thing you need to do is update all of points according to some calculation. After one of points is changed, then you need to update accordingly all of them. For example You change value from 50 to 75 (25 change) then you need to decrease values of all other sliders. Example code:

```
var pointsLength = chart.series[0].data.length;
$.each(chart.series[0].points, function (i, point) {
    $('<input type="hidden" name="slider[]">').val(point.y).appendTo('#sliders');
    // keep reference to the points
    point.slider = $('<div></div>').appendTo('#sliders').slider({
        value: point.y,
        max: 100,
        min: 0,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            var prevVal = point.y,
                step = (ui.value - point.y) / (pointsLength - 1), //split changed value to all sliders
                data = [],
                newVal;

            $.each(chart.series[0].points, function(i, p){
                if(p === point) {
                    data.push({
                        name: p.name,
                        y: ui.value
                    })
                } else {
                    data.push({
                        name: p.name,
                        y: p.y - step 
                    })
                }
            });
            chart.series[0].setData(data);
            $(this).prev().val(ui.value)
        }
    })
    point.slider.children('a').css('background', point.color).text('    ' + point.legendItem.textStr)
})
```

Note: It's not a perfect solution, since when you change to 100% one of sliders, then the rest will go below 0% which is obviously wrong. You need here implement logic which sliders should be changed and how much.

Comment: I have looked at updating and am a bit stuck, can someone please look at the issue I am having. http://jsfiddle.net/3mv5gcto/6/

Comment: How about description of that issue? ;)

Comment: Sure;
- I am unable to 100% for just 1 of the sliders; basically, when I move assume Firefox = 100; other have to become 0; not random numbers;
- The value on tooltip of the graph is not rounding
- When there are more than 10 pies, the colors seem to repeat (that may not be to much of an issue for now)

Comment: 1) For me works fine..? 2) Update `pointFormat`: http://jsfiddle.net/3mv5gcto/7/ 3) Read [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors).

Comment: the 1st one seem to work fine now :(. Tnx for the rest, shall update the ticket and do the needful!

Answer (score 0):

The sliders do not work on a percentage scale, but a relative weighting scale.  Therefore, you should not modify the one slider when another slider is moved.  To illustrate this, go to your demo and move all of the sliders to the middle.  You should see a pie evenly divided into 6 slices.  Now move all the sliders all the way to the right.  The pie doesn't get bigger (I note this because if the analysis were on a percentage scale the pie would be forced to expand).  Instead the program does a relative analysis (comparing the scales of each slider) and comes up with the same result, 6 evenly divided pieces.

If you want to do a percentage based analysis you will need to use a different program.

---

Another option would be to keep the relative scale, but to set the relative scale within the parameter of 100%.  So in the case of 6 pie pieces, if we start out with each piece being equal, and each slider would start out at 16.66% of the way up the slider (most of the way to the left).  If you slide one of the sliders right or left, you must do math to adjust the other sliders accordingly to make sure everything still adds up to 100%.  I would advise that all impacted sliders are adjusted by an equal percentage (be that a % increase or decrease), to account for the gain or loss in the dragged slider.

Comment: Any suggestions to the alternative approach?

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: It’s the same as the graph, except that the end result is not browsers but some business related information that can be manipulated using the sliders and depending on the percentage of those values, I have certain queries. But the UI is the same as in my jsfiddle, I do not have an option to change.